# mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a a form that pulls data from a database(mysql to be specific) and echos the data into the `value` section of `<input>` tags. It doesn't seem to be working  I have coded a view section of my website to do the same thing but from a different table in my database. I use the same code to make making changes easy and if another developer works on my site in the future. Anyway it doesn't seem to be working I'm not sure why though.

The full error  I get:

```
Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /home/caseol5/public_html/jj/admin/news_update.php on line 9
```

Here is line 9 that the error is referring to:

```
$result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
```

I know that both of those function are not null as I did:

```
echo $link
echo $sql
```

before that line after I started feting the error and they both are not null.

Here is the full code segment:

```
$nid = $_GET['nid'];

include ("../sql/dbConnect.php");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM jj_news WHERE news_id = $nid";
echo "<p>The SQL Command: $sql </p>";   
echo "<p>Link: $link </p>";
$result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);


if (!$result)
{
    echo "<h1>You have encountered a problem with the update.</h1>";
    die( "<h2>" . mysqli_error($link) . "</h2>") ;  
}
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);     
$ntitle = $row['news_title'];
$ntline = $row['news_titleline'];
$ndesc = $row['news_desc'];
$nother = $row['news_other'];
```

I have looked into mysqli_query and I can't find anything I'm missing. I have also tired breaking the code down (and running parts of it and it gives the same error. My guess is it something small that I missed. I've looked at other question on this site that do that are a little similar but none seem to help. I've been looking at this for a while now and need another pair of eyes.

**Update**

As requested the contents of my `dbconnect.php` file:

```
$hostname = "localhost";    
$username = "caseol5_jjoes";                
$database = "caseol5_jj_site";              
$password = "password1";                
$link = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $database); 
$link = mysqli_connect($hostname,$username,$password,$database) or   die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));

if (!$link)                                     
{ 
    echo "We have a problem!";

}
```

Comment: Can you show your database connection code? Becaouse the error itself says that your database connection object $link is null means it is not created correctly.

Comment: do not put brackets around your include, it's not needed and is inefficient

Comment: What's the output of your `echo`'s?

Comment: I put the contents of my db connect file in the question

Comment: Is `dbconnect.php` actually the file one directory below your executing file, in the `sql` directory? Can you post the output of `var_dump($link)` right below the include statement? Can you find (ctrl + f) the text "We have a problem!" anywhere in the output (view source, ctrl + u)?

Answer (score 1):

As clearly stated in the error message, `mysqli_query`<sup>[docs](http://php.net/mysqli_query)</sup> expects the first parameter to be a `mysqli` resource. In your case, this parameter is called `$link` but it holds a `null` value. A proper `mysqli` resource is *normally* obtained from connecting with the database by making use of `mysqli_connect`<sup>[docs](http://php.net/mysqli_connect)</sup>

I expect the `../sql/dbConnect.php` file holds the logic to connect with the database. Verify whether the `$link` variable is indeed initialized there. If it's not there, try to find an occurrence of `mysqli_connect` - maybe the resource is set to a different variable.

Without knowing what exactly is in `../sql/dbConnect.php`, your problem right now is that you do not have a valid mysqli resource to use for `mysqli_query`.

Comment: As per his edit, `$link` appears to be not null. `echo "We have a problem!";` would have been executed otherwise.

Comment: @D4V1D According to the documentation, `mysqli_connect` returns an `mysqli` object anyway. Connection status is determined with `mysqli_connect_error()`, not by checking whether the return value is `null`. I have not verified this behavior.

Comment: I'm not sure what happened but it seems to working now I'm really not sure what happened....